Keyboard navigation and selecting cell with mouse doesn't work with custom cellRenderer in ag-grid
I have used custom cellrenderer and handled MouseDown and KeyPress events within the custom renderer. Now when I click on a cell, that doesn't become the focused cell. Also keyboard navigation doesn't work within ag-grid (KeyDown, KeyUP, PageDown, PageUp etc).
How to get the default keyboard navigation and select cell on mouse click work in ag-grid even when using custom cellRenderer?
